# Open sources alternatives to mycurvefit.com

Tags: regression, data-analysis, regression-analysis

I need a framework/library/code that does exactly what MyCurveFit (https://www.mycurvefit.com/#about) does, does it exist? If it doesn't, I'm willing to do it from scratch, in this case, what programming language(s), frameworks and libraries do you recommend? I'm thinking about using R, starting by this course https://www.datacamp.com/courses/writing-efficient-r-code

Comment: NumPy is your best friend here. It's got a built-in polynomial regression facility and powerful array processing.

Comment: Boost.Math has cubic b spline interpolation, barycentric rational interpolation, and a Chebyshev transform. None of these methods can denoise, but all of them are sophisticated. If you're looking to denoise, Boost.Math is looking for someone to implement RiskShrink.